# is it possible to set jpeg(or png) types of images to exe(C++)?

Tags: c++, winapi, user-interface, mfc, gdi+

Now I'm writing an open source project(C++/MFC) and find a beautiful image which is Jpeg type, in Windows API it's easy to change icon with function: `SetIcon`, but I don't want to convert my jpeg file into icon type.

My question: is there a way to set an application's icon using a .jpeg file?

Comment: Can you clarify what you're asking. Your question is confusing. What do you mean by "use Jpeg file like SetIcon"? Do you mean "is there a way to set an application's icon using a .jpeg file?" Or do you mean something else?

Comment: @i have updated my question as you wish, thank you for your suggestion

Comment: In Vista and above program icons can be PNG (256x256x32 bit) but not JPEG.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick for you:

```
Bitmap* icon = new Bitmap("myfile.jpg", TRUE);
HICON hIcon;
icon->GetHICON(&hIcon);
SendMessage(hWnd, WM_SETICON, ICON_BIG, (LPARAM)hIcon);
```

This is of course ignoring error checking, which you might want to add, but otherwise I think this should work. According to [Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms536316%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) this should support the following formats: BMP, GIF, JPEG, PNG, TIFF, Exif, WMF, and EMF.